# Leverage browser caching iis - GTMetric still giving F

Tags: wordpress, caching, iis

I have my web.config file to include:

```
<staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="2.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
```

When I run test it shows the time frame but giving me an F. Any ideas?

https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.tivityhealth.com/IRCSgbCg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gtmetrix is giving this you this rate because your cache time is two days.

In their documentation (https://gtmetrix.com/leverage-browser-caching.html) they suggest to set at least 1 month

> Expiry at a minimum of one month (recommended: access plus 1 year)

Try to put 31 day:

```
<staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="31.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```